# Proverb about wealth and connectedness/friends

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

I remember reading somewhere a proverb. I don't remember exactly how it went. I also vaguely remember it being African, but I'm probably wrong.

In a paraphrased form (in my head) it is: "The wealthy is not the one that has the most, but one that connects the most"

Is there an English proverb or idiomatic expression that express the concept I am referring to?

Comment: You can ask only for English proverbs here, sorry.

Comment: Well, I don't actually know where the proverb came from. I read it in English, so it might be English.

Comment: "The richest people in the world build networks. Everyone else is trained to look for work." *Robert Kiyosaki*

Answer (score 4):

There is this which is attributed to Euripides (Greek 480-406BC):

> *'It is a good thing to be rich, and it is a good thing to be strong, but it is a better thing to be loved of many friends.'*

However, while Euripides has a great deal to say about the shallowness of the pursuit of wealth and power, I can't locate this exact text among his works.

This, however, can be verified from Euripides:

> *'The company of just and righteous men is better than wealth and a rich estate.'*

From Euripide's 'Ægeus', Frag. 7.

Answer (score 3):

From [Google.com/site/onlyquotations](https://sites.google.com/site/onlyquotations/) (but perhaps not idiomatic enough for proverb status):

> Money might make you wealthy, but friends makes you rich.

This quote from [C D Prentice](http://www.inspirational-quotes.info/friendship-quotes.html) [Inspirational Quotes] is perhaps worthy of being considered proverbial:

> A single real friend is a treasure worth more than gold or precious
>   stones.

[Joseph Parry](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/j/josephparr227774.html) ['Brainyquotes'] nicely phrased the metaphor:

> Make new friends, but keep the old; Those are silver, these are gold.

Answer (score 1):

There's an English proverb that expresses the sentiment that **friends are better than money**:

> A friend in the court is better than a penny in the purse.

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=7PMZJqSR4sAC&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=A%20friend%20in%20the%20court%20is%20better%20than%20a%20penny%20in%20the%20purse.&source=bl&ots=ATgtPFSvQ5&sig=K9n5Lkc4UXsROIZHYwoWQx2Vi3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwA2oVChMIzbTcubP7yAIVClssCh1h-QmJ#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Another one is:

> A friend in the market is better than money in the chest.

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=7PMZJqSR4sAC&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=A%20friend%20in%20the%20market%20is%20better%20than%20money%20in%20the%20chest&source=bl&ots=ATgtPFSxS6&sig=4GZ2fKPve7xBS_9Jl1gkrpWVeWE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwA2oVChMIkuqko7T7yAIVIhByCh3MfwW9#v=onepage&q&f=false))